# Freeradius + daloradius privileges not working when connecting to huawei

Tags: linux, authentication, ubuntu, freeradius, radius

I configured freeradius with daloradius and mariadb, I log in to the huawei s6730 device. Authorization passes but privileges level 15 are not assigned. At the same time, the freeradius report shows that it sends the value of the dictionary ((0) HW-Exec-Privilege = 15). What could be the problem?

```
config huawei
aaa
 authentication-scheme default
  authentication-mode local radius
 authentication-scheme radius
  authentication-mode radius
 authorization-scheme default
  authorization-mode local
 accounting-scheme default
  accounting-mode none
 local-aaa-user password policy administrator
  password history record number 0
  undo password alert original
  password expire 0
 domain default
  authentication-scheme radius
  accounting-scheme default
  radius-server default
 domain default_admin
  authentication-scheme default
  accounting-scheme default
  radius-server rad-serv

radius-server template rad-serv
 radius-server shared-key cipher %^%#A}L|PoDpL$%HuI)oC*oEw|.P"_9f8,89U=>FDDyF%^%#
 radius-server authentication 192.168.112.32 1812 source LoopBack 0 weight 100
 radius-server retransmit 2
 undo radius-server user-name domain-included
```

report from freeradius

```
Ready to process requests
(0) Received Access-Request Id 6 from 172.16.0.1:55372 to 192.168.112.32:1812 length 271
(0)   User-Name = "test"
(0)   User-Password = "Secure1qaZ"
(0)   NAS-Port = 0
(0)   Service-Type = Administrative-User
(0)   Framed-Protocol = X.75-Synchronous
(0)   Framed-IP-Address = 172.20.55.4
(0)   NAS-Identifier = "s6730.core"
(0)   NAS-Port-Type = Virtual
(0)   NAS-Port-Id = "slot=0;subslot=0;port=0;vlanid=0"
(0)   Login-IP-Host = 172.20.55.4
(0)   NAS-IP-Address = 172.16.0.1
(0)   Acct-Session-Id = "s6730.c09255255000000000018f2c000000a"
(0)   Huawei-Startup-Stamp = 1674063674
(0)   Huawei-IPHost-Addr = "172.20.55.4 ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff"
(0)   Huawei-Connect-ID = 10
(0)   Huawei-Version = "V200R021C00SPC100B329"
(0)   Huawei-Product-ID = "S6730"
(0)   Huawei-User-Mac = "\000\000\000\006"
(0)   Huawei-Domain-Name = "default_admin"
(0) # Executing section authorize from file /etc/freeradius/3.0/sites-enabled/default
(0)   authorize {
(0)     policy filter_username {
(0)       if (&User-Name) {
(0)       if (&User-Name)  -> TRUE
(0)       if (&User-Name)  {
(0)         if (&User-Name =~ / /) {
(0)         if (&User-Name =~ / /)  -> FALSE
(0)         if (&User-Name =~ /@[^@]*@/ ) {
(0)         if (&User-Name =~ /@[^@]*@/ )  -> FALSE
(0)         if (&User-Name =~ /\.\./ ) {
(0)         if (&User-Name =~ /\.\./ )  -> FALSE
(0)         if ((&User-Name =~ /@/) && (&User-Name !~ /@(.+)\.(.+)$/))  {
(0)         if ((&User-Name =~ /@/) && (&User-Name !~ /@(.+)\.(.+)$/))   -> FALSE
(0)         if (&User-Name =~ /\.$/)  {
(0)         if (&User-Name =~ /\.$/)   -> FALSE
(0)         if (&User-Name =~ /@\./)  {
(0)         if (&User-Name =~ /@\./)   -> FALSE
(0)       } # if (&User-Name)  = notfound
(0)     } # policy filter_username = notfound
(0)     [preprocess] = ok
(0)     [chap] = noop
(0)     [mschap] = noop
(0)     [digest] = noop
(0) suffix: Checking for suffix after "@"
(0) suffix: No '@' in User-Name = "test", looking up realm NULL
(0) suffix: No such realm "NULL"
(0)     [suffix] = noop
(0) eap: No EAP-Message, not doing EAP
(0)     [eap] = noop
(0)     [files] = noop
(0) sql: EXPAND %{User-Name}
(0) sql:    --> test
(0) sql: SQL-User-Name set to 'test'
rlm_sql (sql): Reserved connection (1)
(0) sql: EXPAND SELECT id, username, attribute, value, op FROM radcheck WHERE username = '%{SQL-User-Name}' ORDER BY id
(0) sql:    --> SELECT id, username, attribute, value, op FROM radcheck WHERE username = 'test' ORDER BY id
(0) sql: Executing select query: SELECT id, username, attribute, value, op FROM radcheck WHERE username = 'test' ORDER BY id
(0) sql: User found in radcheck table
(0) sql: Conditional check items matched, merging assignment check items
(0) sql:   Cleartext-Password := "Secure1qaZ"
(0) sql: EXPAND SELECT id, username, attribute, value, op FROM radreply WHERE username = '%{SQL-User-Name}' ORDER BY id
(0) sql:    --> SELECT id, username, attribute, value, op FROM radreply WHERE username = 'test' ORDER BY id
(0) sql: Executing select query: SELECT id, username, attribute, value, op FROM radreply WHERE username = 'test' ORDER BY id
(0) sql: EXPAND SELECT groupname FROM radusergroup WHERE username = '%{SQL-User-Name}' ORDER BY priority
(0) sql:    --> SELECT groupname FROM radusergroup WHERE username = 'test' ORDER BY priority
(0) sql: Executing select query: SELECT groupname FROM radusergroup WHERE username = 'test' ORDER BY priority
(0) sql: User found in the group table
(0) sql: EXPAND SELECT id, groupname, attribute, Value, op FROM radgroupcheck WHERE groupname = '%{SQL-Group}' ORDER BY id
(0) sql:    --> SELECT id, groupname, attribute, Value, op FROM radgroupcheck WHERE groupname = 'test' ORDER BY id
(0) sql: Executing select query: SELECT id, groupname, attribute, Value, op FROM radgroupcheck WHERE groupname = 'test' ORDER BY id
(0) sql: Group "test": Conditional check items matched
(0) sql: Group "test": Merging assignment check items
(0) sql: EXPAND SELECT id, groupname, attribute, value, op FROM radgroupreply WHERE groupname = '%{SQL-Group}' ORDER BY id
(0) sql:    --> SELECT id, groupname, attribute, value, op FROM radgroupreply WHERE groupname = 'test' ORDER BY id
(0) sql: Executing select query: SELECT id, groupname, attribute, value, op FROM radgroupreply WHERE groupname = 'test' ORDER BY id
(0) sql: Group "test": Merging reply items
(0) sql:   HW-Exec-Privilege = 15
(0) sql:   HW-Exec-Privilege == 15
(0) sql:   HW-Exec-Privilege == 3
rlm_sql (sql): Released connection (1)
Need more connections to reach 10 spares
rlm_sql (sql): Opening additional connection (6), 1 of 26 pending slots used
rlm_sql_mysql: Starting connect to MySQL server
rlm_sql_mysql: Connected to database 'radius' on Localhost via UNIX socket, server version 5.5.5-10.6.12-MariaDB-0ubuntu0.22.04.1, protocol version 10
(0)     [sql] = ok
(0)     [expiration] = noop
(0)     [logintime] = noop
(0)     [pap] = updated
(0)   } # authorize = updated
(0) Found Auth-Type = PAP
(0) # Executing group from file /etc/freeradius/3.0/sites-enabled/default
(0)   Auth-Type PAP {
(0) pap: Login attempt with password
(0) pap: Comparing with "known good" Cleartext-Password
(0) pap: User authenticated successfully
(0)     [pap] = ok
(0)   } # Auth-Type PAP = ok
(0) # Executing section post-auth from file /etc/freeradius/3.0/sites-enabled/default
(0)   post-auth {
(0)     if (session-state:User-Name && reply:User-Name && request:User-Name && (reply:User-Name == request:User-Name)) {
(0)     if (session-state:User-Name && reply:User-Name && request:User-Name && (reply:User-Name == request:User-Name))  -> FALSE
(0)     update {
(0)       No attributes updated for RHS &session-state:
(0)     } # update = noop
(0) sql: EXPAND .query
(0) sql:    --> .query
(0) sql: Using query template 'query'
rlm_sql (sql): Reserved connection (2)
(0) sql: EXPAND %{User-Name}
(0) sql:    --> test
(0) sql: SQL-User-Name set to 'test'
(0) sql: EXPAND INSERT INTO radpostauth (username, pass, reply, authdate ) VALUES ( '%{SQL-User-Name}', '%{%{User-Password}:-%{Chap-Password}}', '%{reply:Packet-Type}', '%S.%M' )
(0) sql:    --> INSERT INTO radpostauth (username, pass, reply, authdate ) VALUES ( 'test', 'Secure1qaZ', 'Access-Accept', '2023-08-01 11:54:50.131442' )
(0) sql: Executing query: INSERT INTO radpostauth (username, pass, reply, authdate ) VALUES ( 'test', 'Secure1qaZ', 'Access-Accept', '2023-08-01 11:54:50.131442' )
(0) sql: SQL query returned: success
(0) sql: 1 record(s) updated
rlm_sql (sql): Released connection (2)
(0)     [sql] = ok
(0)     [exec] = noop
(0)     policy remove_reply_message_if_eap {
(0)       if (&reply:EAP-Message && &reply:Reply-Message) {
(0)       if (&reply:EAP-Message && &reply:Reply-Message)  -> FALSE
(0)       else {
(0)         [noop] = noop
(0)       } # else = noop
(0)     } # policy remove_reply_message_if_eap = noop
(0)     if (EAP-Key-Name && &reply:EAP-Session-Id) {
(0)     if (EAP-Key-Name && &reply:EAP-Session-Id)  -> FALSE
(0)   } # post-auth = ok
(0) Sent Access-Accept Id 6 from 192.168.112.32:1812 to 172.16.0.1:55372 length 32
(0)   HW-Exec-Privilege = 15
(0) Finished request
Waking up in 4.9 seconds.
(0) Cleaning up request packet ID 6 with timestamp +18 due to cleanup_delay was reached
Ready to process requests
```